# When trying to display property from JSON data gives undefined

Tags: node.js, json

I am accessing JSON data from endpoint with use of promise. I am able to display the data on console.log but when I try to access a particular field it gives me undefined
Here is my code

```
var json= '';

  const requests = [
      {
        url: 'url1',
      },
      {
        url: 'url2',
      },
    ];
 Promise.map(requests, function(obj) {
      return request(obj).then(function(body) {
        return JSON.parse(body);
      });
    }).then(function(result) {
      result = JSON.stringify(result);
      result = JSON.parse(result);
      console.log(typeof result);  -------> Object
      console.log(result);          -------> Outputs the data perfectly
      console.log(result[0]);          -------> Outputs the data perfectly
      console.log(result.country);   ------> Gives undefined
      console.log(result[0].country);   ------> Gives undefined
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the `result` looks like when you say "Outputs the data perfectly"?

Comment: Is that an array of an array, or is the opening bracket a typo?

Comment: Updated code. Output is ```[[{
      country: 'ac',
      language: 'en',
      audience: null,
      productTypes: [],
      articles: [Array],
      collections: [Array],
      capabilities: [],
      products: [Array],
      series: [],
      contact: [],
      generalPages: [Array],
      commonProductLiteratures: []
    }
  ]
]```

Comment: I am not sure why it comes in as an array of an array, but will `console.log(result[0][0].country)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, your data is coming in as an array of an array. It might be due to the way you are mapping your promises as it is making two requests, but I was able to pull out the json object with `const data = result[0][0];` and then getting the country, as shown below.

```js
const result = [
    [
        { 
            country: 'ac', 
            language: 'en', 
            audience: null, 
            productTypes: [], 
            articles: [Array], 
            collections: [Array], 
            capabilities: [], 
            products: [Array], 
            series: [], 
            contact: [], 
            generalPages: [Array], 
            commonProductLiteratures: [] 
        } 
    ] 
];

console.log(typeof result); // object

const data = result[0][0];

console.log(data);
console.log(data.country);  // ac
```

Comment: I am getting just ```[``` as the output. Any idea why?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `stringify` and `parse` lines? You are already doing `return JSON.parse(body);` so there is no need to stringify and re-parse as it is already a json object?

Comment: Right that works, so I need to use 2 nested loops to loop over whole data to get country right?